# $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\leq n+1$

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove, that the sum of chromatic numbers of graph and it's complement is smaller then the number of vertices incremented by one?

$\chi(G)+\chi(G')\leq n+1$

The notes from my classes say to color the first graph using sequential algorithm with vertices ordered by their degrees (the ones with lowest appear first). We would get $k_1$ colors, then we color the graph $G'$ in the backwards order and get $k_2$ colors, and the sum $k_1+k_2$ in my notes is magically smaller than $n+1$, but I just don't see why...

Comment: See question [#153772](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153772/the-nordhaus-gaddum-problems-for-chromatic-number-of-graph-and-its-complement).

Comment: The answer to this question has a faulty proof.

Comment: Please explain why?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk That proof falsely consider $\overline{H}\subset \overline{G}$ the same as $H\subset G$, which does not hold in general since $H$ may not include all vertices of $G$.

Comment: I fail to see where that is used. The induction hypothesis gives colorings on $G-v$ and $(G-v)'=G'-v$. The degree consideration shows that on at most one of $G,G'$ an extra color is needed to extend to a full proper coloring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a straightforward proof by induction on the number of vertices of $G$.
I leave the induction base to you.

For the induction step,
let $G$ be a graph on $n+1$ vertices, $v$ a vertex of $G$.
So (by the induction hypothesis) we have a $k$-coloring of $G-v$ and an $l$-coloring of $G'-v$, such that $k+l=n+1$.

Now if $d_G(v)<k$ we can extend the coloring on $G-v$ to a proper $k$-coloring of $G$
and use a new color in $G'$ for a total of at most $n+2$ colors.
Otherwise $d_G(v)\geq k$, so $d_{G'}(v)\leq n-k=l-1<l$, so we can extend the coloring on $G'-v$
to a proper $l$-coloring of $G'$ and use a new color on $G$.

Comment: Would it be a $k-$coloring of $G-v$ and a $l-$ coloring of $G^c-v$ such that $k+l\leq n+1$ ? (and not $k+l=n+1$)

Comment: @idm: That is OK as well, but it is not really necessary: a $k$-coloring is a $k+t$-coloring for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: isn't it $n-k\geq l-1$? How do you perform the induction step in that case?

Comment: No, you may assume $k+l=n+1$. A coloring with less than $k$ colors is still a $k$-coloring: you just did not use some of the colors.