# Proof with chromatic index.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for $G = (V,E) $ $$ \chi(G) \chi(\overline{G}) \ge |V| $$
Please for some advices.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000088/prove-chig-chi-barg-geq-n-for-chromatic-number-of-graph-and-its-comple/1000321#1000321